# Have a concept that i'm trying to put a formula to, please help.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I desire a formula where input/output as follows; F(0)=0, F(1)=1, F(3)=2, F(6)=3, F(10)=4,

F(15)=5, F(21)=6, F(28)=7, F(36)=8, F(45)=9, and so on. Can someone help me find F(x)?

Comment: To begin, it is painful to see $3=2$ when $3$ is in fact not equal to $2$.  Recommend rewriting as $f(0)=0,f(1)=1,f(3)=2,f(6)=3,f(10)=4,\dots$ and asking to find $f$.  As for the content of your question, there are uncountably infinitely many such $f$.  There is not enough information to uniquely identify any particular function which begins this way.  If you were to actually *define* the pattern you are following, e.g. $f(1+2+3+\dots+n)=n$, as in the inverse of the triangular numbers, then we could help more.

Comment: If you *are* looking for the inverse triangular number formula, then note that the [triangular numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) follow $T(n)=1+2+\dots+n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.  You may then rearrange the formula and use highschool algebra to find the [inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number#Triangular_roots_and_tests_for_triangular_numbers) LordShark gives below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would
$$f(x)=\frac{\sqrt{8x+1}-1}{2}$$
satisfy you?

Comment: +1, How did you construct that function?

Comment: @JaideepKhare the triangular numbers: $1,3,6,10,15,21,28,\dots$ are well known, the $n$'th triangular number $T(n)=\binom{n+1}{2}=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.  In an attempt to isolate $n$, you get $n^2+n-2T(n)=0$.  Apply the quadratic formula and find $n=\frac{-1\pm \sqrt{1+8T(n)}}{2}$.  Rearranging and recognizing we are interested in giving a positive output gives the form LordShark does above.  Alternatively of course, since the triangular numbers are so well known it could just as easily have been memorized.